# export multiple sheets into one CSV file

Tags: python

---

I imported a table form an excel that contains many sheets.
All the sheet needs to do the data wrangling.

I finished the data wrangling of the first five sheets, which are called data1, data2,data3, data4, data5.

I could export one of them(data1 to data5) to a CSV file. The problem is how can I export all of them into one CSV file with different sheets.

the codes I used are:

```
data3.to_csv('new.csv',index = False)

data2.to_csv('new.csv',index = False)

data1.to_csv('new.csv',index = False)
```

and so on.

But the original CSV file will be covered by the new one.

Comment: [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not helpful. please edit your question. please also read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the CSV file format doesn't have any equivalent of sheets.  You can either write the 5 sets to 5 separate csv files, or append them one after the other into a single file.

Comment: Appreciate.  how about writing all of them into one xlsx file?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.  There are a few modules that allow you to write data in Excel format.  I guess you are already using one of them to read in from Excel?